# variables inside curl string (Java)

Tags: java, curl

Struggling to get a cURL string which includes variables to work.

This works -

```
String command = "Curl --digest -u admin:PASSWORD -X POST -d \"group=CPM CPs&optionalItem=CP&optionalItemInstance=1&action=Value 0\" http://192.168.150.219/action/status";

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I then have two variables which I am trying to insert / replace the original string content -

targetURL (the url)

urlParameters (contains either "0" or "1" and replaces Value)

All my atempts fail, even using just targetURL, either the syntax is wrong or the cURL doesn't execute.

```
String command = "Curl --digest -u admin:PASSWORD -X POST -d \"group=CPM CPs&optionalItem=CP&optionalItemInstance=1&action=Value 1\"" +targetURL;
```

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: All three of your examples have compile errors. Please update your question with what you have actually tried, and the problem you had with each.

Comment: updated with the last (of 50 attemps) which does nothing

Comment: So can you see how the final value of that string differs from the working string you put at the start of your question, assuming that targetURL is "http://192.168.150.219/action/status"?

Comment: I can se that there would be an 'extra' " and I have no idea how to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue was that there was a missing space between the value 0" and the url

Answer (score 0):

Pass them explicitly. For example:

```
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "--digest", "-u", "admin:PASSWORD", "-X", "POST", "-d", "group=CPM CPs&optionalItem=CP&optionalItemInstance=1&action=Value 0", "http://192.168.150.219/action/status")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(is, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

I am not sure, but you might have to encode the `group` parameter with  `URLEncoder.encode("CPM CPs&optionalItem=CP&optionalItemInstance=1&action=Value 0", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: JDK6, no ProcessBuilder

Comment: @Ralph: [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder` in javase 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) "Since: 1.5" And I can confirm I wrote programs successfully using it, in both Java (1.)5 and 6, 12 years ago.

Comment: Thanks, though I get an error when attempting to use ProcessBuilder, maybe because of the old version of Netbeans I am using. My 'code' working at the moment (and saves having to use 50 or so lines of script just to sort out digest authentication). Appreciate your input though.